# Vue js submit function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

There is code to handle the button to close the page and initialize submit

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
  e.returnValue = dialogText;
  return dialogText;
};
```

How to use JavaScript to process this function in Vue JS to send the form through HTML tags?
I did similar things on Jinja, but I can specify data directly in the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind that function to the `beforeunload` window event when the component is initialized.

Example:

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.unload);
},

methods: {
    unload(e) {
        var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
        e.returnValue = dialogText;
        return dialogText;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you're using the `form` element with a submit function, you could just call `unload()` directly? Hard to know whether that would simplify the solution without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I need send data in unload func, but it not work. Code and log: https://pastebin.com/HkQS5KYe

Comment: Have you tried awaiting the `this.test()` function and the `axios` call inside `test()`? It looks like the output of the request will never be logged because you're not waiting for the request to finish before moving on.

Comment: this helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69647485/16067483